# Smoke simulation not working at all

Tags: modeling, texturing, physics, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I followed a tutorial online about smoke simulations, and I am trying to get the smoke to flow down in the domain... Every time I bake, the smoke appears but only around the box and I can't figure out why... I have the screenshot and the .blend file uploaded:

[image: Smoke Simulation]

[image]

Comment: pls also add the link to the tutorial you watched, thx

Comment: @Chris https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxtztAKyPU0

Comment: @Chris keep in mind, I did not fully replicate this tutorial... I did set a collision object but I removed it for the sake of not wanting my project leaked out, and it was close to the actual tutorial in theory but not exactly...

Comment: so you want this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIOWX.gif if yes...i didn't change anything except the path to cache and just set to replay. maybe you had cache issues?

Comment: Have to agree with @Chris, if that's what you try to achieve there's nothing wrong with your file. I actually did not change anything, neither changing the path nor setting it to _Replay_. Just clicked _Free All_ since I had no cached data and then _Bake All_ for a new bake. Worked as I would expect it.

Comment: @Chris huh, that's interesting... Any idea how I could fix that? And I probably wouldn't want the simulation to be that big, would just want it to be something that kinda covers the room a little but not overbearing... That goes out too wide and drops too quickly...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann that's very strange, because that didn't work at all for me... I'd even do free all and then bake and it wouldn't work...

Comment: That's definitely what it was... Deleted the cache file and relocated and it worked fine... Not sure why...